# google.script.run .withSuccessHandler() don't pass the return value to the function if the script is imported as a library

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

**The same function works fine, if the code is not imported and just in the sheet.**

The .withSuccessHandler() don't pass on the return value to the called function.

The code in code.gs returns a Boolean (the log gets it), the function called with .withSuccessHandler() doesn't get it and the variable is *undefined*.

**html**

```
<html>
  <form id="myForm">
  [...]
  <input type="button" value="Submit" 
 onClick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(DataSaved).withFailureHandler(Error).processForm(this.form)"
        />
</form>
<div id="Message"></div>
 <script>
    function DataSaved(ret){
    if(ret==true){
    document.getElementById('Message').innerHTML = "Finished!";
    }else{
    document.getElementById('Message').innerHTML = ret+"Wrong Sheet!";
    }
};
    function Error(err){
    document.getElementById('Message').innerHTML = "An error occurred: "+err;
};
 </script>
```

**code.gs**

```
function processForm(myForm) {
  var data = myForm.data
  var fu = ParseExport(data)
  console.log(typeof fu);console.log(JSON.stringify(fu))
  return fu
}
```

The resulting line is: `undefinedWrong Sheet!`

**Stackdriver**

```
Stackdriver-Protokolle
29.06.2019, 19:39:11
FEHLERBEHEBUNG
boolean
29.06.2019, 19:39:11
FEHLERBEHEBUNG
true
```

I don't know where to look for the mistake anymore. Even moved the google.script.run function in the script block to test if it changes anything (it don't). The error handler works fine...

Comment: Try `console.log(typeof fu);console.log(JSON.stringify(fu))`. Provide `ParseExport` return type/value

Comment: added the extended logging (see above).

Comment: Is `ret` defined somewhere else? Can you try moving the script block  above the form block?

Comment: Also, try just returning true `function processForm(myForm) {return true}`

Comment: moving the script block didn't help and ``ret`` and ``err`` are the only variables in the html. Renamed it anyway to be sure, but didn't change anything.

Comment: and the empty ``processForm(myForm)`` didn't help either.

Comment: Maybe boolean is the problem. Try returning a string: `function processForm(myForm) {return "true"}`. Btw, if you're using `exec`, you must redploy the app every time you change something.

Comment: Narrowed down the problem.
The script (and html) is imported as a library on other sheets. On a test build with the code on the same sheet, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake, as the importing Sheet has a wrapper class to handle the the call to the imported script functions, which needs to pass the return along, too.